# PlotRange is sometimes ignored

Tags: plotting

I have a relatively simple plot, and `PlotRange` argument seems to be ignored sometimes (Mathematica 12.1), any suggestions how to get it to respect the argument?

```
plot[s_] := 
  LogPlot[{1/i, (1 - 1/i)^(2 s) 1/i}, {i, 1, 100}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 2}];
plot[1]
plot[100]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry.  I responded too quickly previously.  I think the issue is that with a `LogPlot` you can't get to zero for the "y" axis.  So you'd need something like `PlotRange -> {10^-4, 2}`.

Comment: The bugs tag is reserved for questions where the problem has been vetted by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug. Please do not use this tag for new questions.

Comment: Compare your examples to the graphs without `PlotRange`. For `plot[1]`, there's a y-axis tick for 2 above the labeled tick at 1. For `plot[100]`, the difference in the y-axis is there, but small. With the default `Ticks -> Automatic` the next *labeled* tick displays at `PlotRange -> {0, 5}` for `plot[1]`.

Comment: Perhaps `PlotRange -> {All, 2}`?